# If I use spring data rest+ spring data jpa will it guarantee there will be zero code left in service layer and Dao layer to code manually?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I need to know if we use spring data rest + spring data jpa then will it replace all the code that we need to type manually in those layers.? So then what else we have left to develop in the back-end?I mean is it really that awesome? Please explain the limitations if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write a DAO. If you need custom queries beyond simple CRUD there are different ways to create them as well as different repository interfaces to extend (PagingAndSorting etc).

Then you @Autowire your repository into the service layer to apply business logic.

No DAO necessary.

Comment: Yeah then what about the service class because when we use spring data rest then it will provide some endpoints too no ?

Comment: It does provide endpoints - so for a very simple use case you could get away without even writing a controller.